# using button instead of submit in jquery validation engine

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validation-engine

I am using input type = button instead of input type = submit to submit a form values. Now I want to validate all text box, select box and check box while clicking that button, how do I do that? help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below steps,

1. Get the value of the text box like,

   ```
   var controlValue = $("#controlid").val();
   ```
2. The do the validation using the condition as required, say for example as,

   ```
   if(txtBox1 != "")
   {
       alert("error"); 
   }
   ```
3. If all conditions passed then submit the form.

   ```
   $("form[0]").submit();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery validator supports a method called `valid`

you can call like

```
$('form').valid();
```

run this on the button click